# NoMethodError at / undefined method `page_media' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling, rubygems

NoMethodError at /
undefined method `page_media' for nil:NilClass

indexapp/controllers/homepage_controller.rb

```
  before_action :set_track_page_status
  def index
     @cms_page     = Page.find_by_content_filename("homepage.en.yml")
     @homepage_cms = HomepageCms.first
     @page_medium  = @cms_page.page_media.order("id ASC")
     @roots        = Category.roots
  end
end
```

How can I fix this this issue on Ror? The homepage does not load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify slightly:

```
@page_medium  = @cms_page.page_media.order("id ASC") if @cms_page.page_media
```

Comment: Still the same
NoMethodError at /
undefined method `page_media' for nil:NilClass

Comment: before_action :set_track_page_status
  def index

Answer (score 0):

`@cms_page` seems not to have any associated `page_media`s.

A quick fix could be:

```
@page_medium  = @cms_page.try(:page_media).try(:order, "id ASC")
```

Comment: It gave another error which I am not sure why.

.row.thumbnail-image.catalogs
    .col-sm-4.item
      = link_to link_category("Fashion Accessories") do
        = image_tag("#{@page_medium[2].file.url rescue asset_url(@homepage_cms.image_custom_product_1)}", class: "img-responsive")

Comment: p
          = @page_medium[2].additional_text
          | &nbsp; <i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>
      = link_to link_category("Men's Clothing") do
        = image_tag("#{@page_medium[3].file.url rescue asset_url(@homepage_cms.image_custom_product_2)}", class: "img-responsive")
        p
          = @page_medium[3].additional_text

Answer (score 0):

@cms_page is nil. So check if really have a Page with content filename equal to "homepage.en.yml" in the database.
And like Carson Cole pointed out (with some modification..):

```
@page_medium  = @cms_page.page_media.order("id ASC") if @cms_page
```